# What are the latitude and longitude of a circle?

Tags: android

In Android, if I have a circle's radius and center value, how could I measure the latitude and longitude of about 1 km periphery of that circle?

Comment: Please avoid to write things like "Plz help me" and "Plz help me fast", remember that people do this for fun.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Please avoid writing things like"?

Answer (score 2):

```
Horizontal = x-axis = Longitude
Vertical = y-axis = Latitude
```

Comment: Sir i dont get u exactly..plz explain more

Answer (score 1):

Latitude and longitude are terms necessary to define a position on a sphere, where two angles are necessary. These terms have no relevance to a circle, which exists only in one plane.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem to solve as the distance between each latitude and longitude varies depending upon where on the globe you are (I'm sure some maths boffin could do it, but it is beyond me). For instance at the north and south pole one degree longitude measures no distance at all, but at the equator one degree can be several kilometers. If however your search only relates to a small are of the globe, then a you can make a reasonable approximation by using 1km = x degrees where x is the correct value where you are.

Answer (score 0):

Terms "circle", "radius" implies a 2D flat plane geometry whereas "latitude", "longitude" implies a geographical coordinates on a 3D ellipsoid.

Putting these problems asides, let's assume, in fact that your "circle" is a point on the surface of our Earth and, the "radius" is a distance from this point. This will correct your terms so they define a 3D problem.

If a projection is given. Then we can specify the "center" in planar geometry coordinates (X, Y). We can specify all points distance "R" in geometry coordinates as (X + R * cos(phi), Y + r * sin(phi)) then we can use the projection to convert the geometry coordinates from planar to geographic i.e. longitude, latitude. The problem is 1000s of projections exists and not all a valid across the entire Earth.

Alternatively, you can define your 3D ellipsoid in 3D space using (X, Y, Z) coordinates. Then the wording of your problem must change. The "circle" because a sphere whose point is on the surface of the ellipsoid and the "radius" is the radius of the sphere. To compute all points distance "R" from the sphere you will need to intersect the sphere with the ellipsoid using trigonometry. After you have done this, you can convert the resultant 3D coordinates back to longitude, latitude based on the definition of your ellipsoid.